# Html.BeginForm to call an action not in an Area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-areas

How can I use Html.BeginForm to link from within an area to an action and controller not in an area? I am using:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id =    "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
```

When I click the button it is looking for the controller in the area but it is not there.

Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: I think that there's another overload for `BeingForm` that accepts an area, try providing `""` or `null` to that parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks on helpful comments, The solution is:

```
 using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly providing `null` or empty string `""` as the `area`:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { area = null, id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
```